# Why does a 12 inch Macbook refuse to turn on with a lot of battery remaining unless it is plugged in?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

This Early 2015 12 inch MacBook was showing 75% battery remaining, and when I plug in my iPhone to try to record the iPhone, the Macbook began to sleep and refused to turn on when I press the power button.  It showed the "Plug Me In" icon.

So I unplugged the iPhone and started charging it, and then it would turn on right away, and showed a 69% battery level.

So why did it refuse to be on at such a high level of battery remaining and how can it be fixed or prevented?

P.S. It is a Macbook 12 inch that was introduced in 2015... so the battery is just a little more than one year old.

Comment: There is no 1st gen Macbook 12"... first was 2015 according to everymac. Anyway - have you checked the battery with something like [CoconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is a 12" MacBook (implying at most it's still a little shy of being a couple of years old) and not a 13" model (which could be a lot older), then the first thing I'd do is reset the System Management Controller.

For a 12" MacBook you reset the SMC as follows:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> 
   (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

Once you've done this report back on how it went.

If in fact it's not a 12" MacBook, then please update your question with the exact model so we can make sure we're providing accurate advice for your model.

Answer (score 1):

If a battery driven device (a MacBook in this case) doesn't turn on *without* the AC adapter plugged in it means that **the battery cannot supply enough current to power the device.**

> This first generation Macbook 12 inch was showing 75% battery remaining...

The "75% battery remaining" is a *calculation* based on how much charge the battery has verses it's full capacity and the electrical current it's capable of delivering at that moment.

When the battery drops below a certain amount of voltage, the overcharge/undercharge protection circuit kicks in and kills power to the device.  What's happening with your battery is that it can no longer hold a charge.  Even though it has *calculated* 75% charge left, the voltage drops too low too quickly and the MacBook will turn off/go to sleep.

Basically, your battery can no longer hold a charge and is going into hibernate/sleep mode.  This is expected behavior.

This being a 2015 MacBook, it's unusual for a battery to have such a short lifespan, though it's not unheard of.

Batteries typically have a useful life of 3 to 5 years. So, less than 2 is concerning.  If your product is still under warranty, you should get the battery replaced by Apple; it's covered under [AppleCare](http://www.apple.com/support/products/mac.html) if that is still in effect.

If you don't have AppleCare, it can still be fixed relatively inexpensively.

According to [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Retina+MacBook+2015+Lower+Case+Assembly+Replacement/44155), the battery is glued into position and extremely difficult to remove.  It can be done, but like I said - it's extremely difficult.  Also, it's very difficult to source the part from reputable vendors.

[image]

However, the good news is that if you have the technical skill, you can replace the entire bottom case assembly ([PN# 661-02245](http://radnex.us/macbook_12-inch-lower-case-assy)) for this unit as it includes the battery ($130USD at the time of this post).  [Ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Retina+MacBook+2015+Lower+Case+Assembly+Replacement/44155) has a guide for you to follow or you can take it into an Apple Repair shop.

Comment: the first generation Macbook 12 inch... which was introduced in 2015