# Is there a way to make Macbook 12 inch or Macbook Air not charge an iPhone when plugged in?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, usb, battery, charging

That's because, to record iPhone 7 Plus's screen, I need to plug it into Macbook Air or Macbook 12 inch.

Now, when QuickTime records the screen of iPhone, it probably use a lot of processor power (together with hard drive power constantly).  That probably is a lot of power consumption all at once.

I have noticed that [in some cases, my Macbook 12 inch would even shut itself down when battery level is at 75% or 69%](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274122/why-does-a-12-inch-macbook-refuse-to-turn-on-with-a-lot-of-battery-remaining-unl), probably due to power consumption bigger than the battery can afford.

So if my iPhone 7 Plus still has 80% of battery, I really don't need to draw power from the Macbook.  Is there a way to tell the Macbook USB not to charge the iPhone?

P.S. I cannot plug in the Macbook to AC adapter, as I might be recording the iPhone screen in the car or on the go, so there might not be power outlet readily available.

Comment: One idea, untested.  I have a battery pack which I use for powering my iPhone when I am away from AC.  Here is one for sale:  https://www.amazon.com/Yell-4000mAh-Adapters-Smartphones-Tablets/dp/B00ATNCCUO?th=1.  If you could find a suitable USB hub, you could power the hub from the battery pack while using the hub for data between the MacBook and iPhone.  By "suitable" I mean a hub that might come with an AC adapter that you can unplug from the hub and connect to the battery pack in place of the AC adapter.  An untested idea.

Comment: I also have a USB battery from Anker that can power a 12 inch Macbook using USB-C... so I just need a hub so that it can power the Macbook as well as letting the iPhone connect to the Macbook 12 inch... kind of complicated... oh well... if only iPhone has a screen recording option... almost all Android phones can do it

Comment: One possibility that we don't charge the iPhone is by using Airshou or Airserver, so that the audio / video data is streamed to the Mac by Wireless (or Bluetooth, I am not sure yet). One disadvantage is, what if you are on the road and there is no Wifi? Also, sometimes there seemed to be dropped frame, so it is not as reliable as using the USB cable