# Where is battery data stored on macbooks?

Tags: battery

Apps like CoconutBattery can display various data on a MacBook battery like

- Manufacturing date
- Design capacity
- Current capacity
- Wear level

Once you swap a battery the application can instantly detect and get data from the new battery. This makes me believe that the data is stored on the battery itself.

Where is all this (MacBook) battery data stored? **On the battery itself?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That info is stored on the battery itself.  With the exception of current capacity which is calculated, everything else is stored on the battery’s control chip.

Usually, on the same PCB as the [battery protection circuit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287593/119271) there’s a control chip that balances the voltage, measures capacity etc.  It’s on this chip that things like the serial number, cycle count, etc, are stored.  This is why when changing out a battery this info is “reset” without having to do anything on your Mac.

As for utilities like Coconut Battery, they’re good, but you can get the same info for free with [built in commands](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328981/119271).

Comment: as for temporary info, either of SMC, NVRAM has it I guess?