# My MacBook Pro battery disabled/damaged after using software?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, hardware, charging

I replaced my MacBook Pro battery six months ago and have been using a charge limiter app called AlDente to maintain its health. I used it for a month but suddenly this morning, my battery stopped working. I checked the system report, and it seems like the battery is no longer installed.

I tried resetting the SMC and uninstalling AlDente, but my battery still isn't being detected. I am also using Windows via Boot Camp, and the battery is not being recognized there either.

Is it possible that this app has caused damage to my battery, or could this issue be related to a software error? Any solutions?

My OS: Catalina
Model: Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2014

Comment: What brand/make/model of battery did you put in your laptop. It is possible that you got a defective battery? Can you return it under warranty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked the system report, and it seems like the battery is no longer installed… I tried resetting the SMC and uninstalling AlDente, but my battery still isn't being detected.

The controller chip on the battery has died.

First, it’s important to note that modern devices don’t just “communicate” to the raw battery connection.  You”re not plugging in few  AA batteries and the Mac can count cycle times, get ID numbers, etc.  All of this info is handled by the [controller chip](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/383110/119271) attached to it.

If your Mac, whether macOS or Windows cannot see it, it means that it is no longer able to talk with that *chip*. As far as it can tell, the chip simply isn’t there.

**You need to get the battery replaced**.

While the chip is bad and the battery itself may be good, this is not something that is typically replaced either by home DIYers or pros,  I’m not saying it can’t be done, it’s just not typical,

Finally, you don’t need any software to limit the charging of your battery:

- [Battery Full Alert](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/287591/119271)
- [How to preserve MacbookPro battery from degradation?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/194700/119271)