# How to prevent the battery capacity degrading using a PowerBook G4 with Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: battery, unix, dual-boot, powerbook

I have a 2005 PowerBook G4 which I dual-boot Mac OSX 10.5.8 and Ubuntu 16.04 XFCE. The 'book runs both OSs quite well but I have noticed that using Ubuntu has the effect of reducing the battery capacity quite qucikly. For instance today, my aftermarket battery was showing "full" at 64% but after using Ubuntu for 45 minutes it went to 0% and shut down. When I recharged it, it only went back up to 35%. This has happened before and I am writing this post from OSX while I re-calibrate the battery. Is there any way to use Ubuntu but be gentler on the battery? I normally use Ubuntu more than OSX as it is still getting security updates and I like some of the applications that run on it.

Update: The re-calibration seems to be stuck at 37% so not going very well.

Comment: This sounds like you have a faulty battery. Ubuntu might not have the power management capabilities needed to prevent premature discharging but it is no “harder” on a battery than macOS would be running with power saving feature disabled. As for charging, Ubuntu has no control over the maximum capacity - that’s a physical attribute of the battery itself

Comment: Also, battery calibration is to fix the accuracy of what the OS *reports* the actual charge to be, not what the battery can charge to. Ubuntu doesn’t regulate charging, the SMC does in conjunction with the “intelligence” built into the battery itself.  Other than resetting the SMC, the only thing you can do is get a different battery to fix this.

Comment: In Mac OSX, Coconut Battery reports battery capacity as 67% but it won't charge up past 37% There is every chance the battery is faulty as was a cheap aftermarket one. Seller claimed 5200mAh capacity but was 4400mAh when it arrived.

Comment: Coconut (not a fan; [you can get this info for free](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328981/119271)) gets the capacity info from the chip on the battery. It's similar to the gas guage on your car - it's a static "known" value (there is some calculation involved based on age, cycles, voyage, amps etc.) The full charge is a calculation based on an actual reading of the battery (actual voltage) and then compared to the max charge value. If the battery has dead cells, the SMC nor the battery pack IC will know about it. That's the discrepancy you're seeing.